# How to call a class function from a tkinter button?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I am trying to create a program which prints something everytime i click a button, but it has to bee done using a class.

When i run my code, i get this error : NameError: name 'self' is not defined

**(I dont want to put the test_button inside the class, because this is just a part of a much bigger program, and if i fix my problem in this way, then some other functions wont work.)**

Any help is much appreciated!!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x400")
window.configure(background='grey')

class person():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        print('something')


#title label
label = tk.Label(window, text = "title",bg = '#42eff5',fg ='red',width = 35, height = 5).pack()
#button
test_button = Button(window,text='something',command = person.test(self),width= 11,height = 2,bg='blue',activebackground = 'blue',fg='white').place(x = 10,y = 30)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the person, and call the method on that person.

```
somebody = person()
test_button = Button(.., command=somebody.test, ...)
```

Comment: I tried that before and instead of running the specific function, in this case the test function in run the whole class

Comment: Oh nevermind my bad, it works, there was another bug, which was causing this error.